# ubuntu 16.04 LTS freezes randomly in dell precision 7920 workstation

Tags: freeze

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS freezes randomly. PC, keyboard and mouse not respond when it freezes and only option is force shutdown. we are not able find the solution for this issue. we are using Nvidia driver 430 and workstation is Dell precision 7920. Please help me out with this problem